# How to fix treeItem.DisplayMemberPath when I apply the theme?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, themes

I have a TreeView which is bind to a list of objects: 
when I have no theme 
treeItem.DisplayMemberPath = "Name"
works well,  but when I apply the theme like “BubbleCreme.xaml” instead of “Name” I have “System.DataEntity.DynamicProxies.food45484545…” in my TreeView
Here is the treeView Style in the theme if needed

```
<!-- Treeview -->
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeView}" TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.5,1.5,.75,.75" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1.5" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource SecondaryColor}" />
                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
                <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" CornerRadius="4">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="InnerShadow" Opacity="0.25" Margin="-1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="6" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition Height="6" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border Background="{StaticResource SecondaryBrush}" CornerRadius="2.5,0,0,0">
                                <Border.OpacityMask>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                                        <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
                                                <TranslateTransform X="0.5" Y="0.5" />
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <GradientStop />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Border.OpacityMask>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="{StaticResource SecondaryBrush}" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Border.OpacityMask>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.OpacityMask>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="{StaticResource SecondaryBrush}" Grid.Column="2" CornerRadius="0,2.5,0,0">
                                <Border.OpacityMask>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                                        <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
                                                <TranslateTransform X="-0.5" Y="0.5" />
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <GradientStop />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Border.OpacityMask>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="{StaticResource SecondaryBrush}" Grid.Row="1">
                                <Border.OpacityMask>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,.5" StartPoint="0,.5">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.OpacityMask>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="{StaticResource SecondaryBrush}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" OpacityMask="#00000000" />
                            <Border Background="{StaticResource SecondaryBrush}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
                                <Border.OpacityMask>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,.5" StartPoint="0,.5">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="1" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.OpacityMask>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="{StaticResource SecondaryBrush}" Grid.Row="2" CornerRadius="0,0,0,2.5">
                                <Border.OpacityMask>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                                        <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
                                                <TranslateTransform X="0.5" Y="-0.5" />
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <GradientStop />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Border.OpacityMask>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="{StaticResource SecondaryBrush}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                <Border.OpacityMask>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.OpacityMask>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="{StaticResource SecondaryBrush}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" CornerRadius="0,0,2.5,0">
                                <Border.OpacityMask>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                                        <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
                                                <TranslateTransform X="-0.5" Y="-0.5" />
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <GradientStop />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Border.OpacityMask>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <ItemsPresenter Margin="5" x:Name="TreeItems" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- TreeviewItem -->
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Grid Background="{x:Null}" x:Name="Root">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF999999" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.75" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Opacity="0" x:Name="grid">
                        <Border x:Name="Background" CornerRadius="12" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness=".5,0.5,1,1">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1.75" StartPoint="0.5,-.5">
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource SecondaryColor}" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" Offset=".01" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" Offset=".3" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource SecondaryColor}" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="Halo" CornerRadius="12" Opacity=".65" Background="{StaticResource SecondaryBrush}" OpacityMask="{StaticResource HaloMask}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="Expander" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False">
                        <ToggleButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="Transparent">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.StrokeThickness)">
                                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1.25" />
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".7" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)">
                                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="45" />
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2 2 5 2">
                                        <Grid x:Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin=".25,.8" Height="10" Width="5">
                                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                <TransformGroup>
                                                    <RotateTransform />
                                                </TransformGroup>
                                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Stroke="{x:Null}" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" StrokeThickness=".75" Data="M 0,0 L 0,10 L 5,5 Z" Fill="{StaticResource TextBrush}" Opacity="0" />
                                            <Path x:Name="Border" Stroke="{StaticResource TextBrush}" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" StrokeThickness=".75" Data="M 0,0 L 0,10 L 5,5 Z" Fill="{x:Null}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ToggleButton.Template>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <Button Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" x:Name="Header" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" IsTabStop="False" Grid.Column="1" ClickMode="Hover" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Padding="8,3,8,3">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="hover" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".5" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".55" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Grid x:Name="hover" Opacity="0">
                                        <Border x:Name="Background" CornerRadius="12" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness=".5,0.5,1,1">
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1.75" StartPoint="0.5,-.5">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource SecondaryColor}" Offset="0" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" Offset=".01" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" Offset=".3" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource SecondaryColor}" Offset="1" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Border.Background>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border x:Name="Halo" CornerRadius="12" Opacity=".65" Background="{StaticResource SecondaryBrush}" OpacityMask="{StaticResource HaloMask}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" x:Name="content" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="ItemsHost" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" TargetName="Expander" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.3" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.25" />-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.3" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" />-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00.001" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.5" />-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--<DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.3" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" />-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Don't insert whole of your code or project. It can be unsafe and it makes a too uneasy task for readers. Try to insert the code relevant to your question or where you think the error is. [See this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225698/is-it-correct-to-post-whole-of-the-code-in-question)